# After I use exe4j packaging, user.dir is no longer the original result

Tags: exe4j

After I use exe4j packaging, user.dir is no longer the original result. Please ask how to solve this problem, that is, how to get the path where the current working path.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tt3QW.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
[Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Om the "Executable info" step of the wizard, deselect the "Change working directory to" check box in order to keep the current directory as the working directory.